# Computation using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I try to compute a loop with "for" in R but I found the same value everywhere I don't understand where I am wrong

```
s= exp(3.9847926338)
g= exp(0.0008496878/log(3.8867428919)) 
SQlisse2012=sum(Qlisse2012)
output <-matrix(unlist(Qlisse2012), nrow = 111, byrow = TRUE)

for(i in 1:111) {
     mak_x[i,1] <-1-s*g^((output[i,1]^i)*(SQlisse2012-1))
} 
mak_x
```

output is a 1X1 matrix 
So should be mak_x.
Why do I get the same value for all the mak_x. Can please someone help me?
Thank you.

```
> dput(head(unlist(Qlisse2012)))
c(0.00196369415769458, 0.000607220407674348, 8.90217045411847e-05, 
1.06625941681469e-05, 2.63131336125785e-05, 3.61959487783429e-05)
```

Comment: You need no loop here. R is vectorized, hence you might can run `mak_x[,1] <-1-s*g^((output[,1]^c(1:111))*(SQlisse2012-1))`. For further help, please provide also the `Qlisse2012` object.

Comment: @Jimbou good answer I deleted mine which is the same

Comment: what value is it? did yo check the values of 1-s*g^((output[i,1]^i)*(SQlisse2012-1))?

Comment: Qlisse2012 is a list of number that I transformed in a matrix. Now R is telling me  _incorrect number of subscripts on matrix_

Comment: OK, could it be that it your code has to be sth like this? `1-s*g^((output[,1]^c(1:111)*(SQlisse2012[1:100]-1))`